# Writing a predicate to balance an equation using some operators

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `balance(Xs, Eqn)` so that e.g. if the list `Xs` was `[2,3,5,7,11]` then some operators (+,-,*,\,=) should be placed between elements of the list (kept in the same order) to balance the equation Eqn. Some examples:

```
Eqn = (2=3-(5+7-11))
Eqn = (2=(3*5+7)/11)
```

etc.

I can use =.. and =:= to extract and compare the left and right of the equation but I'm not sure how to go about getting different operators between the elements in the first place.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Elaborating on CapelliC's clue about using `append/3`, you can do, `append([HL|TL], [HR|TR], L)` to split `L` into two non-empty lists. You will want a recursive predicate to apply an operator on each pair of legs through the binary parse tree. When you've created two expressions, say, `E1` and `E2`, you can then compare with `E1 =:= E2`. It is actually, in implementation, simpler than it sounds. :)

Answer (score 2):

generate-and-test will make easy to solve...

If the equality is to be considered 'special', as it is usually, then split the list in 2 not empty lists (append/3 is handy to do this).

Then recurse both lists inserting each operator, and finally just use `Left =:= Right`.

Backtracking among operator placing and the initial list splitting will find all solutions, if there are...

Easy placement sample:

```
place_ops([N],N) :- !.
place_ops([N|T],E) :- member(Op, [+,-]), E =.. [Op,N,P], place_ops(T,P).
```

yields

```
?- place_ops([1,2,3],E).
E = 1+ (2+3) ;
E = 1+ (2-3) ;
E = 1- (2+3) ;
E = 1- (2-3).
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing : how could the place_ops predicate be edited to include e.g. `E = (1-2)+3` ?

Comment: try swapping N and P in E =.. [...]

Comment: That reversed the order of the expression but didn't include the example I mentioned above.

Comment: recursing on the right of the input list it's akward... maybe reverse and apply the left recursion